# How can I animate with .class in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, svg

I can animate the #ID Div tag to move around, but I cant call the .class Div Tag to move. How can I do that correctly ?

```
.myClass {
                width: 40px; height: 40px;float:left;padding: 1px; margin:3px; 
                position:absolute; left:50px; top:60px; background:blue; color:white;
          }
```

In the HTML:

```
<div class="myClass">Insert image2</div>
<div class="myClass"><img src="jef-frog.gif"width="50">DIV myCLASS</img></div>

function randomRange(min,max) {
                return Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
            }

            /* Generate some random starting position */
            var startmyClassX = randomRange(50,100);
            var startmyClassY = randomRange(50,100);

var item2 = $(".myClass"),cycle1;

function runItem2() {
                /* Set a the starting position to be random by editing the css */
                $(".myClass").css("left", startItem2X+"px");
                $(".myClass").css("top", startItem2Y+"px");
                $(".myClass").svg(onLoad);

                (cycle2 = function() {
                 var m = randomRange(50,100);
                 var n = randomRange(75,150);
                 myClass.animate({top:'+='+m, left:'+='+n},2000);
                 myClass.animate({left:'-='+n},2000);
                 myClass.animate({left:'+='+n, top:'-='+n},2000);
                 myClass.animate({left:'-='+n},2000)
                 myClass.animate({top:'+='+m},2000,cycle2)

                 })();

            }

runItem2();
```

Anyone can help to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: there are many syntax errors with your code. what is `startItem2X`? what is `svg` a plugin?

Comment: startItem2X i m trying to set the X position of the image

Comment: Patrick, but when I try to animate my DIV ID tag ... it does moves. 
Please see the demo >> http://jsfiddle.net/cHStS/

Comment: @PatrickKlug - there are examples on the [`.animate()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) that use `+=` and `-=`.

Comment: May i know what would be a better way to animate multiple images?

Comment: @nnnnnn okay, I didn't know this was possible. comment removed

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable `var item2 = $(".myClass")`, but then later in your code where you should be using `item2` you use `myClass`:

```
myClass.animate({top:'+='+m, left:'+='+n},2000);
...
myClass.animate({top:'+='+m},2000,cycle2)
```

Either rename the variable to `myClass` or change the later code to use `item2`. (You've also declared a variable `cycle1` and then later used `cycle2`.)

Note that the callback you provide to the [`.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) will be called once per element being animated, so with `$(".myClass")` matching two elements you're going to be doubling the number the animations each time you restart the cycle.

Note also that in your demo you've got two things moving independently, but if you animate all elements with the same class from that one animation function then all the elements will move the same way.